# How to create turtles with random xycor but also in the center of a patch?

Tags: netlogo

I am working with the daisyworld model and am planning to add a predator to the model which will eat the daisies (this is for a class project). I have successfully added the predators (brown rabbits eat the white daisies, grey rabbits eat the black daisies). But in order for them to eat the daisies, their coordinates have to line up perfectly causing very little "eating" to occur. Is there a way for me to generate rabbits with random xy cor but be generated in the exact center of the pixel?

```
globals [
  max-age               ;; maximum age that all daisies live to
  global-temperature    ;; the average temperature of the patches in the world
  num-blacks            ;; the number of black daisies
  num-whites            ;; the number of white daisies
  scenario-phase        ;; interval counter used to keep track of what portion of scenario is currently occurring
  ]

breed [daisies daisy]
breed [brown-rabbits brown-rabbit]
breed [grey-rabbits grey-rabbit]

patches-own [temperature]  ;; local temperature at this location

daisies-own [
  age       ;; age of the daisy
  albedo    ;; fraction (0-1) of energy absorbed as heat from sunlight
  daisy-black ;; boolean if daisy is black
]
brown-rabbits-own
   [energy]
grey-rabbits-own
   [energy]


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Setup Procedures ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape daisies "flower"
  ask patches [ set pcolor gray ]

  set max-age 25
  set global-temperature 0

  if (scenario = "ramp-up-ramp-down"    ) [ set solar-luminosity 0.8 ]
  if (scenario = "low solar luminosity" ) [ set solar-luminosity 0.6 ]
  if (scenario = "our solar luminosity" ) [ set solar-luminosity 1.0 ]
  if (scenario = "high solar luminosity") [ set solar-luminosity 1.4 ]

  seed-blacks-randomly
  seed-whites-randomly
  ask daisies [set age random max-age]
  ask patches [calc-temperature]
  set global-temperature (mean [temperature] of patches)
  update-display
  ;reset-ticks


  create-grey-rabbits grey-rabbit-number
  [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "rabbit"
   set size 1.5
   set color grey
    set energy random (2 * grey-rabbit-gain-from-food)
  ]

   create-brown-rabbits brown-rabbit-number
  [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "rabbit"
   set size 1.5
   set color brown
    set energy random (2 * brown-rabbit-gain-from-food)
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to seed-blacks-randomly
   ask n-of round ((start-%-blacks * count patches) / 100) patches with [not any? daisies-here]
     [ sprout-daisies 1 [set-as-black] ]
  ask daisies [set daisy-black true]
end

to seed-whites-randomly
   ask n-of floor ((start-%-whites * count patches) / 100) patches with [not any? daisies-here]
     [ sprout-daisies 1 [set-as-white] ]
   ask daisies [set daisy-black false]
end





;to daisy-black
;  ifelse color = 0
;  [daisy-black true]
;  [daisy-black false]
;end



;ask daisies if color = 0 [set daisy-black true]

;ask daisies if color = 9.9 [set daisy-black false]


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Runtime Procedures ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


to go
  ask grey-rabbits [
    move
    set energy energy - 1
    eat-black-daisies
    death
    reproduce-grey-rabbits
  ]
  ask brown-rabbits [
    move
    set energy energy - 1
    eat-white-daisies
    death
    reproduce-brown-rabbits
  ]

   ask patches [calc-temperature]
   diffuse temperature .5
   ask daisies [check-survivability]
   set global-temperature (mean [temperature] of patches)
   update-display
   tick
   if scenario = "ramp-up-ramp-down" [
     if ticks > 200 and ticks <= 400 [
       set solar-luminosity precision (solar-luminosity + 0.005) 4
     ]
     if ticks > 600 and ticks <= 850 [
       set solar-luminosity precision (solar-luminosity - 0.0025) 4
     ]
   ]
   if scenario = "low solar luminosity"  [ set solar-luminosity 0.6 ]
   if scenario = "our solar luminosity"  [ set solar-luminosity 1.0 ]
   if scenario = "high solar luminosity" [ set solar-luminosity 1.4 ]
end

to move
  rt random 20
  lt random 20
  fd 1
end


to eat-black-daisies ;grey rabbits eat black daisies
 ask grey-rabbits
  [if any? daisies-here with [daisy-black = true]
    [let prey one-of daisies-here; with [daisy-black = true]
      if prey != nobody
      [ask prey [die]
      set energy energy + grey-rabbit-gain-from-food]
    ]
  ]
end


to eat-white-daisies ;brown rabbits eat white daisies
; ask brown-rabbits
;  ;[if any? daisies-here with [daisy-black = false]
;  patch-here
;    [let prey one-of daisies-here with [daisy-black = false]
;      if prey != nobody
;      [ask prey [die]
;        set energy energy + brown-rabbit-gain-from-food]
;    ]
;  ;]
end








to reproduce-grey-rabbits
  if random-float 100 < grey-rabbits-reproduce [
    set energy (energy / 2)
    hatch 1 [rt random-float 360 fd 1]
  ]
end

to reproduce-brown-rabbits
  if random-float 100 < brown-rabbits-reproduce [
    set energy (energy / 2)
    hatch 1 [rt random-float 360 fd 1]
  ]
end

to death
  if energy < 0 [die]
end

to set-as-black ;; turtle procedure
  set color black
  set albedo albedo-of-blacks
  set age 0
  set size 0.6
end

to set-as-white  ;; turtle procedure
  set color white
  set albedo albedo-of-whites
  set age 0
  set size 0.6
end

to check-survivability ;; turtle procedure
  let seed-threshold 0
  let not-empty-spaces nobody
  let seeding-place nobody

  set age (age + 1)
  ifelse age < max-age
  [
     set seed-threshold ((0.1457 * temperature) - (0.0032 * (temperature ^ 2)) - 0.6443)
     ;; This equation may look complex, but it is just a parabola.
     ;; This parabola has a peak value of 1 -- the maximum growth factor possible at an optimum
     ;; temperature of 22.5 degrees C
     ;; -- and drops to zero at local temperatures of 5 degrees C and 40 degrees C. [the x-intercepts]
     ;; Thus, growth of new daisies can only occur within this temperature range,
     ;; with decreasing probability of growth new daisies closer to the x-intercepts of the parabolas
     ;; remember, however, that this probability calculation is based on the local temperature.

     if (random-float 1.0 < seed-threshold) [
       set seeding-place one-of neighbors with [not any? daisies-here]

       if (seeding-place != nobody)
       [
         if (color = white)
         [
           ask seeding-place [sprout-daisies 1 [set-as-white]  ]
         ]
         if (color = black)
         [
           ask seeding-place [sprout-daisies 1 [set-as-black]  ]
         ]
       ]
     ]
  ]
  [die]
end

to calc-temperature  ;; patch procedure
  let absorbed-luminosity 0
  let local-heating 0
  ifelse not any? daisies-here
  [   ;; the percentage of absorbed energy is calculated (1 - albedo-of-surface) and then multiplied by the solar-luminosity
      ;; to give a scaled absorbed-luminosity.
    set absorbed-luminosity ((1 - albedo-of-surface) * solar-luminosity)
  ]
  [
      ;; the percentage of absorbed energy is calculated (1 - albedo) and then multiplied by the solar-luminosity
      ;; to give a scaled absorbed-luminosity.
    ask one-of daisies-here
      [set absorbed-luminosity ((1 - albedo) * solar-luminosity)]
  ]
  ;; local-heating is calculated as logarithmic function of solar-luminosity
  ;; where a absorbed-luminosity of 1 yields a local-heating of 80 degrees C
  ;; and an absorbed-luminosity of .5 yields a local-heating of approximately 30 C
  ;; and a absorbed-luminosity of 0.01 yields a local-heating of approximately -273 C
  ifelse absorbed-luminosity > 0
      [set local-heating 72 * ln absorbed-luminosity + 80]
      [set local-heating 80]
  set temperature ((temperature + local-heating) / 2)
     ;; set the temperature at this patch to be the average of the current temperature and the local-heating effect
end

to paint-daisies   ;; daisy painting procedure which uses the mouse location draw daisies when the mouse button is down
  if mouse-down?
  [
    ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [
      ifelse not any? daisies-here
      [
        if paint-daisies-as = "add black"
          [sprout-daisies 1 [set-as-black]]
        if paint-daisies-as = "add white"
          [sprout-daisies 1 [set-as-white]]
      ]
      [
        if paint-daisies-as = "remove"
          [ask daisies-here [die]]
      ]
      display  ;; update view
    ]
  ]
end

to update-display
  ifelse (show-temp-map? = true)
    [ ask patches [set pcolor scale-color red temperature -50 110] ]  ;; scale color of patches to the local temperature
    [ ask patches [set pcolor grey] ]

  ifelse (show-daisies? = true)
    [ ask daisies [set hidden? false] ]
    [ ask daisies [set hidden? true] ]
end


; Copyright 2006 Uri Wilensky.
; See Info tab for full copyright and license.
```

Comment: Try out `random-pxcor`:  https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-pcor

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking whether 2 turtles are exactly on the same spot, I would use patch-here to see if they are on the same patch.

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-here

Comment: Hello, thank you for commenting on my question. You will see I added my entire code to the question. I am trying to have the brown rabbits eat white daisies and grey rabbits eat black daisies. How would you utilize "ask-patches" within this code?

Comment: I see that you already use daisies-here, which checks the entire patch, not the center. so 'centering' shouldn't be the issue. How big are your patches? if you have very tiny patches, the chances of them being on the same patch is low, but that is only solved by either looking `in-radius` or using distance, https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distance